# An approximation: 2*number of events = twice the probability

Tags: probability, approximation

My statistical mechanics textbook uses an approximation to derive a well-known result. The approximation is:

Suppose for an event, the probability of an outcome is P. For n events, the probability of the outcome is n * P, assuming both P is small, and n isn't too large.

This approximation makes "intuitive" sense, but where does it come from mathematically, and how accurate is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual probability of getting the outcome at least once over $n$ trials can be computed pretty easily:
it is one minus the probability that the outcome never occurs.
So if the outcome has a probability of $p$ of occurring in an individual trial, then over $n$ trials the probability is
$$
1 - (1 - p)^n
$$
Going from here to the approximation in your book is just an application of the binomial theorem.
\begin{align*}
1 - (1 - p)^n
&= 1 - \sum_{i = 0}^n {n \choose i} (-1)^i p^i \\
&= 1 - \left(1 - np + {n \choose 2}p^2 - {n \choose 3}p^3 + \cdots \right) \\
&= np - {n \choose 2}p^2 + {n \choose 3}p^3 - \cdots \\
&\approx np
\end{align*}

This approximation will be most accurate when $p$ is small.  For a precise analysis of the error, we can use the [Lagrange Remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html): since $np$ is the first degree Taylor approximation to $f(p) = 1 - (1-p)^n$, the remainder term is given by
$f''(t) \frac{p^2}{2!}$ for some $0 < t < p$.  Then we compute
$|f''(t)| = |-n(n-1)(1-t)^{n-2}| < n(n-1)$, so the error is
bounded above by
$$
\frac{n(n-1)}{2!} p^2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical situation for a binomial distribution. Let's compute the probability of the complementary, that is, the probability of that the event doesn't occur in $n$ trials. This is
$$(1-P)^n$$
Now, the probability that you want to compute is
$$1-(1-P)^n=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom nj (-P)^j$$
Since the first term of the sum is $1$, this make
$$nP-\binom n2 P^2+\binom n3 P^3-\ldots=nP+O(P^2)$$
when $P$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's consider the total number of outcomes to be $N$, and favorable to be $k$, and probability $\frac{k}{N}=p$

Now changing the number of outcomes the number of outcomes, we have $$\begin{align}p'&=\frac{nk}{N+(n-1)k}\tag{*}\\&\approx\frac{nk}{N}=np\end{align}$$

This obviously holds true if $N>>k$ and $n$ is small.

$(*)$ This depends on what you call "changing number of favorable outcomes". In case favorable outcomes change, keeping the total constant, then this isn't an approximation, it becomes *exactly* true.